# JSP AND AJAX code for dropdowns

Tags: ajax

Hey guys..
I need a JSP code which uses ONLY AJAX and not .net or php.
It should basically consider of 2 dropdowns, something like COUNTRY NAME and STATE NAME.
The STATE NAME dropdown should get refreshed once when we select DIFFERENT COUNTRY in the COUNTRY DROPDOWN..
Any text before of after the dropdowns should not be affected..

thank you

Answer (score 0):

what is this JSP only ajax ?  :)

Study Well

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/10/27/sprinkle-ajax-magic-into-struts-webapp.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but, anyone still looking for a solution, this tutorial may help you
http://www.dzone.com/snippets/dependant-dropdowns-using-ajax